# How to perform url in asp.net core mvc with angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an asp.net core project and choose an angular template, everything is ok, but I can't call any Controller Or action through URL (browser) like as MVC. its always call default route config "Home", "Index".
I Need it when I don't provide any URL. but when I type hardcoded URL, it doesn't work. by the way, I am new in angular, but I fully familiar with MVC. I think I did any mistake.
Here my route on startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
```

//This is for mvc/ api

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

//this is for angular

```
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```

Comment: it should work fine. That's just the default route, but a specific URL should make it to the controller. Can you post your angular code, and MVC controller?

Comment: I don't create any angular code yet, but create a sample like old mvc. I create a Employee class, and controller and view as well. when I change the "spa-fallback" route to  new { controller = "Employees", action = "Create" }); then its work fine, and I can crud as well, but when i type Employees/Edit or any other, then the action not call, only call from the default route action.